# New joiners vs Leavers in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have to find new joiners and leavers from the following data-set:
[image: This is my data-set]

I have used this dax to find the leavers:

```
leavers = IF(COUNT(EmployeeDetail[Date of Leaving])=BLANK(),0,
                COUNT(EmployeeDetail[Date of Leaving]))
```

But i am confused in finding new joiners.
Also, i have to find Bad hires (<60 days active).
How can i write dax for it?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what exactly you are trying to do.  Because "finding the new joiners" seems a bit confusing.  Everybody is a new joiner at some point.  So i'm not sure what exactly is your goal.

Comment: Ok .. got it what u are saying...

Comment: how to find second scenario that is finding bad hires

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the bad hires, you can add a calculated column and use it as filter

```
BadHire = IF( ISBLANK('Table'[leave date] ) ,0 , IF( datediff('Table'[join date],'Table'[leave date],DAY) > 60 ,0 ,1 ) )
```